# identifier expected ! how can I fix?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2013, web-applications

Pls don't give me negativity because I can't ask more question !!

[Here is the image of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gHIds.png)

Answer (score 1):

You need to define namespace name, for example `namespace MyNamespace { public class CardModel { ... } }`

Note: Each class in C# must reside inside namespace. Each specified namespace must have name.

Comment: what exactly should I write mate ?

Comment: Whatever you want

Comment: @Toni You don't have Card class defined in your project, or you need to import namespace in which Card class resides.

Comment: so pls what should I need to do ?!